# Bar plot showing odd error line

Tags: python, matplotlib

The error black line in the middle of the horizontal bar plot below is extremely long even though `stds` is:

```
array([  1.14428879e-01,   3.38164768e-01,   5.58287430e-01,
         7.77484276e-01,   9.95380202e-01,   1.58493526e-08,
         8.69720905e-02,   8.64435493e-02,   5.12989176e-03])
```

[image]

The code for plotting this was:

```
  pl.barh(ind,means,align='center',xerr=stds,ecolor='k', alpha=0.3)
```

Why is this?

Comment: None of the plotted error bars seem to match what has been plotted. Could you add some more detail to the question, perhaps example data + script to reproduce the error.

Comment: I had the same thought, but I think the bars are plotted from the bottom up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errorbars in your plot are correct. Take e.g. the longest one, with value `9.95380202e-01` = `0.995380202` ≈ `1.0`. When you pass a *N*×1 array of values to `xerr` the values are plotted as ± the value, i.e. they will span twice the length. So an `xerr` with value `1.0` will span `2.0` units, from `width - 1.0` to `width + 1.0`. To avoid this you can create a 2×*N* array where one row consists only of zeros, see example below.

---

From the documentation of [`pyplot.bar()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) (same applies to `pyplot.barh()`):

> Detail: xerr and yerr are passed directly to [`errorbar()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar), so they can
>   also have shape 2xN for independent specification of lower and upper
>   errors.

From the documentation of [`pyplot.errorbar()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar):

> xerr/yerr: [ scalar | N, Nx1, or 2xN array-like ]
>
> If a scalar number, len(N) array-like object, or an Nx1 array-like
>   object, errorbars are drawn at +/-value relative to the data.
>
> If a sequence of shape 2xN, errorbars are drawn at -row1 and +row2
>   relative to the data.

---

An example showing the different "combinations" of errorbars:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(9)
y = np.random.rand(9) * 10

stds = np.array([1.14428879e-01, 3.38164768e-01, 5.58287430e-01,
                 7.77484276e-01, 9.95380202e-01, 1.58493526e-08,
                 8.69720905e-02, 8.64435493e-02, 5.12989176e-03])

# Create array with only positive errors
pos_xerr = np.vstack((np.zeros(len(stds)), stds))

# Create array with only negative errors
neg_xerr = np.vstack((stds, np.zeros(len(stds))))

#Create array with different positive and negative error
both_xerr = np.vstack((stds, np.random.rand(len(stds))*2))

fig, ((ax, ax2),(ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(9,5))

# Plot centered errorbars (+/- given value)
ax.barh(x, y, xerr=stds, ecolor='k', align='center', alpha=0.3)
ax.set_title('+/- errorbars')
# Plot positive errorbars
ax2.barh(x, y, xerr=pos_xerr, ecolor='g', align='center', alpha=0.3)
ax2.set_title('Positive errorbars')
# Plot negative errorbars
ax3.barh(x, y, xerr=neg_xerr, ecolor='r', align='center', alpha=0.3)
ax3.set_title('Negative errorbars')
# Plot errorbars with different positive and negative error
ax4.barh(x, y, xerr=both_xerr, ecolor='b', align='center', alpha=0.3)
ax4.set_title('Different positive and negative error')

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image: Different combinations of xerr]